# move a subview down when scrolling UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, vertical-scrolling

I have a UITableViewController with static cells.
I add a view in the lower left corner.
I wish for this subview to always stay "glued" to the lower left corner and come down/up with the user scrolling.

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you mean: scroll along with the content, but stop at the tableview's bounds.  That's just what headers and footers do.  A footer could be empty except for a view on the left side.  This would appear as a lower left corner.

Comment: @danh I do mean scroll along with the content, can you please elaborate with code example

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the link, it only requires very slight alteration to have a view stick to the bottom left corner instead of the bottom middle.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html